# Select Case error 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I loop inside an array and check cells values, however, sometimes it can happen that checked cell is "**#DIV/0!**", then my macro breakes. How to change it? I have tried two things but will no positive effect.

```
vRange = Range(Cells(ShiftRow, 4), Cells(ShiftRow - 3, TheLastColumn)).Value

Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To TheLastColumn
    Select Case vRange(4, i)
        Case Is = "#DIV/0!"
            vRange(1, i) = ""
        Case Is = "1"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i)
        Case Is = "2"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 1)
        Case Is = "3"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 2)
        Case Is = "I"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i)
        Case Is = "II"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 1)
        Case Is = "III"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 2)
        Case Else
            vRange(1, i) = ""

    End Select
Next i
```

I also tried: `Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` .

Comment: can you check the values of `vRange` in the Locals window? It seems like your loop should be something like `For i = 1 To UBound(vRange, 2)` ? `Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` should be the correct way, so the error might be somewere else.

Comment: What if you do `If IsError(vRange(4, i)) then vRange(4, i) = ""` before your Select Case?

Comment: @maers . try the error trapping in my answer below

Comment: @Slai I used `i = 4 To TheLastColumn` because `LBound(vRange) To UBound(vRange)` was only looping through 1 to 4. But In fact `UBound(vRange, 2)` is fine. However, overall the problem is still present.
@Rémi It works! Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't seem like you need `Case CVErr(xlErrDiv0)` because your `Case Else` will handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CStr([#DIV/0!])` returns the string `"Error 2007"` so you can change the code like this

```
vRange = Range(Cells(ShiftRow - 3, 4), Cells(ShiftRow, TheLastColumn)).Value ' the second cell is usualy the bottom right, but Excel takes care of that
Dim i As Integer

For i = 4 To UBound(vRange, 2)
    Select Case CStr(vRange(4, i))
        Case "1", "I":     vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i)
        Case "2", "II":    vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 1)
        Case "3", "III":   vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 2)
        Case "Error 2007": vRange(1, i) = "" ' optional because Case Else can handle it
        Case Else:         vRange(1, i) = ""
    End Select
Next i
```

Comment: I'm not an expert (obviously) but it seems like the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to trap the **Error** with the `On Error Resume Next`, and add the following code instead of your Select Case:

```
Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
For i = 4 To TheLastColumn

    Select Case vRange(4, i)
        Case Is = "#DIV/0!"
            If err.Number = 13 Then ' this is Error number 13 when deviding by zero
                vRange(1, i) = ""
                err.Clear
            End If

        Case Is = "1"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i)
        Case Is = "2"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 1)
        Case Is = "3"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 2)
        Case Is = "I"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i)
        Case Is = "II"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 1)
        Case Is = "III"
            vRange(1, i) = vRange(3, i - 2)
        Case Else
            vRange(1, i) = ""

    End Select

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks! Both you and Remi had similar idea, I will go with one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Slai's excellent answer, this information might be helpful to future readers.

I have a .csv file - plain text - across which I am running a script to colorize any cell that is not a number. So, for each cell, I am running this function:

```
Function fnIsNumber(Value) As Boolean
   fnIsNumber = Evaluate("ISNUMBER(0+""" & Value & """)")
End Function
```

Some of the cells have the (plain text - remember this is a csv) value `#DIV/0!`. The above function abends on these cells, with the message `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

In Excel macros, even *the string* `#DIV/0!` evaluates to "Error 2007", so I had to modify the function as Slai recommended above:

```
Function fnIsNumber(Value) As Boolean
   If CStr(Value) = "Error 2007" Then
      fnIsNumber = False
   Else
      fnIsNumber = Evaluate("ISNUMBER(0+""" & Value & """)")
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells that contain an error return a [different data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262707(v=vs.60).aspx) (variant of subtype error) than non-error cells.  This complicates comparison.

One approach is to nest one case statement within another.  The outer case checks for the cell type (error/non-error).  The inner case choses what to do, based on non-error value.  I've used the [TypeName function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/TypeName-Function-581cb27e-4faa-45ba-a94b-5d96e43195ff?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) to determin what data type I am working with.

This example works on the active cell.  Update the values to test.

```
Sub test()
' Update contents of active cell to test.
' Test cases:
'
'   Value   Output
'   1/0     Error: Error 2007
'   1       One
'   Hi      Hi
'   <other> Other


    ' Outer case checks for errors.
    Select Case TypeName(ActiveCell.Value)
        Case "Error"
            ' We have an error.
            MsgBox "Error: " & CStr(CVErr(ActiveCell.Value))

        Case Else
            ' Non-error.
            ' Inner case checks cell content.
            Select Case ActiveCell.Value
                Case 1
                    ' User entered 1.
                    MsgBox "One"

                Case "Hi"
                    ' User entered "Hi".
                    MsgBox "Hi"

                Case Else
                    ' Unknown user entry.
                    MsgBox "Other"

            End Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

You could improve this sub by adding a second inner case, that checks for different error codes.